# Call top posts in different divs

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, posts

I want to have my latest post show up with all info(title, author, thumbnail, and content) but only the title of the second most recent post in another div. Here is my code. It renders the divs correctly but the 'title' in the second div is the 'title' of the latest post still.

```
                <div id="blog-pane">


        <div id="blog-post">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



            <div id="post-title">

                <?php the_title(); ?>

            </div>

            <div id="post-author">

                <?php the_author(); ?>
                &nbsp;
                <?php the_date(); ?>
                &nbsp;
                <?php the_time(); ?>

            </div>

            <div id="post-image">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

            </div>

            <div id="post-text">

                <?php the_content(); ?>

            </div>      

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>


        </div>


        <div id="post-link-1">

            <?php

                query_posts( 'p' );

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                the_title();

                endwhile;


                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to introduce some skip logic to have it skip the first post,

```
<div id="post-link-1">

            <?php

                query_posts( 'p' );
                $count = 0;
                while ( have_posts() ) { 

                       if ($count++ == 0) {
                           the_post();
                           continue;
                       }

                the_post();

                the_title();

                }


                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: That shows the content for the 2nd most recent post followed by the title of the 3rd most recent post